# chain string expression linq

Tags: sql, linq

In traditional sql we can chain expression according to if statements.

for example lets say I have variable called "firstName" and I want to get from database all users according to the value in this variable(if empty get all users)

so I will chain the sql string like that

```
string sql="";
if(firstname!="")
sql=String.format(" And firstname='{0}',firstName)

.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandType.Text,"select * from users where 1=1" + sql)
```

Is there a way to copy this Technique to linq expression?

something like

```
from U in user
where 1=1 & sql
select U
```

Comment: That's definitely *not* a good practice with SQL. Actually, string concatenation is considered a very bad practice as it exposes you to SQL Injection attacks, results in slow performance *and* is harder to write and maintain than parameterized queries. LINQ does allow real chaining, eg simply add `.Where()` calls to the query one by one. The result will be a proper SQL statement without ifs or `1=1` tricks

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos , Of course I'm using  parameterized queries this is just short example to present an idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to method syntax instead of query syntax, and chaining is easy.

```
var query = user.Select(u => u);  
if(firstname!="")
    query = query.Where(u => u.firstname = firstname);
```

queries in query syntax are converted at compile-time, so there's not a mechanism to "inject" sql at run time using query syntax.

Comment: Also worth noting, LINQ to SQL or EF will create parameterized queries and pass eg `firstname` as a parameter.

Comment: If I have multiple variables(firstname,lastname,phone...)   will this technique run multiple sql queries againts db or just one ?

Comment: what did you mean by "the select is not necessary here"

Comment: @baaroz just one query when you materialize it with `ToList` or `foreach` loop

Comment: @baaroz I just took that out - actually it does make a difference in how `query` is declared.  You can forget I said that :)

Comment: @baaroz To expand on @Grundy's response, the query doesn't actually get executed until you materialize it with a `ToList` or `foreach`.  So anything you chain to the query _before_ that would be incorporated into one query.